# How to make a bootable flash from my already installed Ubuntu?

Tags: boot, system-installation, live-usb, usb-creator, cloning

I need to make a bootable media(USB) from my installed version of Ubuntu as it is on my hdd and then boot from it to install this system in other computers. How do i do that?

Comment: Please don't post the exact same question (http://askubuntu.com/questions/797466/10-04lts-from-installed-on-hd-to-usb-stick).

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to AskUbuntu, Jeff!

I haven't tried it myself, and I don't know if it's been tested with your version of Ubuntu, but it looks like there is a way!

The steps are a a bit too long and too involved for me to include here, so I'll just include the link to the Ubuntu Community Wiki page that hosts the instructions.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MakeALiveCD/DVD/BootableFlashFromHarddiskInstall

I hope this helps!